# CouchDB with Erlang version 18?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, server, couchdb, version

Does couchDB work with erlang version 18? I'm running an ubuntu server on apache2.

I first install erlangs latest version 18 and then couchDB. It fails to install couchdb when it gives this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is this because it needs the erlang version R16?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this because it needs the erlang version R16?

When 1.6.1 released, latest Erlang was 17, so it's the highest supported version. Erlang 18 introduced some breaking changes, so without patches CouchDB won't compile. However, this all was fixed already in source code repository both for 1.x and 2.x branches.

Comment: This means that there should not be any problem right? Could you check this out please http://askubuntu.com/questions/696930/couchdb-unmet-dependencies-couchdb-bin-1-6-1-0ubuntu5-held-broken-package

Comment: Do you have suggestions on what else could be done to fix this?